# img attr src in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox

I have a problem in Firefox to change img src,
but it works in IE and Chrome,
this is my code below:

```
var ss = xxx.toDataURL();
var img = '#xxxImg' + $('#ImgIndex').val();
$(img).attr({
    src: xxx.toDataURL()
});
```

firefox show '**ReferenceError: src is not defined**',
I have no solution to fix it,
please help me

Update:
src have value:
data:image/png;base64, ***********
but img still don't show the new Image,
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476679/preloading-images-with-jquery)
but don't worked for me,
or just preload it wrong side?

```
$(img).attr(
    "src", xxx.toDataURL()
);
$(img).preload();
```

Comment: Can you please provide a snippet that showcases the issue.

Comment: what do you want?a screen print?

Comment: We need an example to work with, as outlined: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I found the problem,it dont have height in firefox